# Load huggingface model from cache dir

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I tried to load the `Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored` model from my local huggingface cache. I have already downloaded it, as shown by typing `huggingface-cli scan-cache`:

```
REPO ID                                REPO TYPE SIZE ON DISK NB FILES LAST_ACCESSED LAST_MODIFIED REFS LOCAL PATH                                                                           
-------------------------------------- --------- ------------ -------- ------------- ------------- ---- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ehartford/Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored model           130.1G       16 23 hours ago  3 weeks ago   main /home/hanyuan/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored 
openai/clip-vit-base-patch32           model           608.9M        8 10 hours ago  2 weeks ago   main /home/hanyuan/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--openai--clip-vit-base-patch32           

Done in 0.0s. Scanned 2 repo(s) for a total of 130.7G.
```

According to documentation on Huggingface, the cache of the model is stored in `~/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored`.

But when I tried to load it like the following,

```
model_name_or_path = "ehartford/Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored"
# model_name_or_path = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1"
cache_path = "~/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored"

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, torch_dtype=torch.float16, cache_dir=cache_path)
```

I got the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../blobs/2122720188751bb5b1d1a28480cbca2d216c63f2' -> '/home/hanyuan/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored/snapshots/24768a6df2e4694b960ea84d2f304ad1ae46804d/config.json'
```

I checked the directory tree of the cache by typing `tree .` and the config file was there, as shown below. I am not sure why it could not be read.

```
.
├── blobs
│   ├── 01e07f1446f8170b1bc8243b0be505682e30972a725715a943f6dec397b0bdbb
│   ├── 0ce58615abc6af1d095318c1c31cc853c390f177
│   ├── 2122720188751bb5b1d1a28480cbca2d216c63f2
│   ├── 24c825e8623d0142f36b44a8c4fea5cdba4c077baf4258ea9110293fe3379bae
│   ├── 2dde03c3cdaece3d431e4c7a2d650cfa60bd70d1cf3cbe7e45c015a94dca92a5
│   ├── 3c785ec9b45647110067ceb1b8e1f2559c1f4e084b6df8ca62767ad6119b0e56
│   ├── 63aad63bd26bd5690d6142b070562ca04df77733cad6f7d86cd2e53f9d908a2e
│   ├── 8490ad0b9f5aef9f7c4c4fb563040e814552c09c53a8fb37149493419b491933
│   ├── a27aee057c3ac1702636dfb4234096128e260cbcdf938c7dcd78593ab4db716e
│   ├── aa1b98b9be148e6b771f6682312418b00536fd52bf9ed2c5291f8c4284e1ec24
│   ├── aed54566783e3bbed22f21cbfd1c2bfc31216746978c544ca0dee58f5ce68913
│   ├── b0ab5af08a5032a1389008381b0f8d732f56f831278c9da8a5b8dc128b653440
│   ├── da181241735d617312ecf6313e4e42a4aabd1d5081c0885f71291c4849afd5b7
│   ├── e59c5ff81545fc5ec474dd37341837fe19fa8659b1ad76555f612376befb8f43
│   ├── f5a6bc28dbc2a4846a7b18effd16f4ce3fb080d5d0a30f850ee4ab42b8b82cb1
│   └── fd2cf4302c5216dda202be0cbd13406e4e92756acdd05c660713ade87b8d7646
├── models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored
├── refs
│   └── main
└── snapshots
    ├── 24768a6df2e4694b960ea84d2f304ad1ae46804d
    │   ├── config.json -> ../../blobs/2122720188751bb5b1d1a28480cbca2d216c63f2
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00001-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/aed54566783e3bbed22f21cbfd1c2bfc31216746978c544ca0dee58f5ce68913
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00002-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/24c825e8623d0142f36b44a8c4fea5cdba4c077baf4258ea9110293fe3379bae
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00003-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/f5a6bc28dbc2a4846a7b18effd16f4ce3fb080d5d0a30f850ee4ab42b8b82cb1
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00004-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/8490ad0b9f5aef9f7c4c4fb563040e814552c09c53a8fb37149493419b491933
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00005-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/da181241735d617312ecf6313e4e42a4aabd1d5081c0885f71291c4849afd5b7
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00006-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/a27aee057c3ac1702636dfb4234096128e260cbcdf938c7dcd78593ab4db716e
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00007-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/3c785ec9b45647110067ceb1b8e1f2559c1f4e084b6df8ca62767ad6119b0e56
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00008-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/fd2cf4302c5216dda202be0cbd13406e4e92756acdd05c660713ade87b8d7646
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00009-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/b0ab5af08a5032a1389008381b0f8d732f56f831278c9da8a5b8dc128b653440
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00010-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/aa1b98b9be148e6b771f6682312418b00536fd52bf9ed2c5291f8c4284e1ec24
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00011-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/01e07f1446f8170b1bc8243b0be505682e30972a725715a943f6dec397b0bdbb
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00012-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/63aad63bd26bd5690d6142b070562ca04df77733cad6f7d86cd2e53f9d908a2e
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00013-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/2dde03c3cdaece3d431e4c7a2d650cfa60bd70d1cf3cbe7e45c015a94dca92a5
    │   ├── pytorch_model-00014-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/e59c5ff81545fc5ec474dd37341837fe19fa8659b1ad76555f612376befb8f43
    │   └── pytorch_model.bin.index.json -> ../../blobs/0ce58615abc6af1d095318c1c31cc853c390f177
    └── 86636d5c1e6e3b2634594c4fd97d7e6102bdf5aa
        ├── config.json -> ../../blobs/2122720188751bb5b1d1a28480cbca2d216c63f2
        ├── pytorch_model-00001-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/aed54566783e3bbed22f21cbfd1c2bfc31216746978c544ca0dee58f5ce68913
        ├── pytorch_model-00002-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/24c825e8623d0142f36b44a8c4fea5cdba4c077baf4258ea9110293fe3379bae
        ├── pytorch_model-00003-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/f5a6bc28dbc2a4846a7b18effd16f4ce3fb080d5d0a30f850ee4ab42b8b82cb1
        ├── pytorch_model-00004-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/8490ad0b9f5aef9f7c4c4fb563040e814552c09c53a8fb37149493419b491933
        ├── pytorch_model-00005-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/da181241735d617312ecf6313e4e42a4aabd1d5081c0885f71291c4849afd5b7
        ├── pytorch_model-00006-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/a27aee057c3ac1702636dfb4234096128e260cbcdf938c7dcd78593ab4db716e
        ├── pytorch_model-00007-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/3c785ec9b45647110067ceb1b8e1f2559c1f4e084b6df8ca62767ad6119b0e56
        ├── pytorch_model-00008-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/fd2cf4302c5216dda202be0cbd13406e4e92756acdd05c660713ade87b8d7646
        ├── pytorch_model-00009-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/b0ab5af08a5032a1389008381b0f8d732f56f831278c9da8a5b8dc128b653440
        ├── pytorch_model-00010-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/aa1b98b9be148e6b771f6682312418b00536fd52bf9ed2c5291f8c4284e1ec24
        ├── pytorch_model-00011-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/01e07f1446f8170b1bc8243b0be505682e30972a725715a943f6dec397b0bdbb
        ├── pytorch_model-00012-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/63aad63bd26bd5690d6142b070562ca04df77733cad6f7d86cd2e53f9d908a2e
        ├── pytorch_model-00013-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/2dde03c3cdaece3d431e4c7a2d650cfa60bd70d1cf3cbe7e45c015a94dca92a5
        ├── pytorch_model-00014-of-00014.bin -> ../../blobs/e59c5ff81545fc5ec474dd37341837fe19fa8659b1ad76555f612376befb8f43
        └── pytorch_model.bin.index.json -> ../../blobs/0ce58615abc6af1d095318c1c31cc853c390f177

6 directories, 49 files
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> cache_dir (str or os.PathLike, optional) — Path to a directory in
> which a downloaded pretrained model configuration should be cached if
> the standard cache should not be used.

As you seem to be using the standard cache

1. Try not passing the cached_dir parameter at all.

Honestly, I think this is the solution for your case.

If that doesn't work try

2. Replace `cache_path = "~/.cache/huggingface/hub/..."` with `cache_path = "/home/hanyuan/.cache/huggingface/hub/..."`, as it might be a problem with the path expansion.

Another thing to try if the above don't work is

3. Replace the path with `/home/hanyuan/.cache/huggingface/hub/`. There's a possibility it's looking for a path to the where the cache is stored, instead of the path of the already cached model.

Anyways, start from 1 and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will check if your suggestions work on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the folder path that contains `config.json`.
In your case it's like that:

```py
model_name_or_path= "~/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--ehartford--Wizard-Vicuna-30B-Uncensored/snapshots/24768a6df2e4694b960ea84d2f304ad1ae46804d"

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
```